# DB2 (Cursor IS Found) INVALID KEYWORD "FOUND"

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, cursor

I'm having a serious problem with DB2 Cursor.
When I'm opening it I cant know is there any records in it or not?

And also I'm writing my stored procedure in IBM® Data Studio Version 4.1.0.0

Comment: Please add the Code to your answer as text, not as an image - this way other users can copy it which makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You must run the `FETCH` statement to check, if there are records in the result set. But you can't do it since you return the result to a caller.

So, the 1-st solution would be to use, let's say, (Declared | Created) Global Temporary Table to `INSERT SELECT` into it with checking, if any rows were inserted (using [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_getdiagnostics.html) statement), and then open either cursor1 on this (C|D)GTT, or cursor2.

The 2-nd solution would be to combine both select statements into a single one like below:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NUMBER) RN
  , T.*
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 AS NUMBER, T1.*
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 T1
    --WHERE 1=0
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS NUMBER, T2.*
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 T2
  ) T
) T
WHERE RN=1;
```

The idea is to `UNION` both result sets, rank them by their constant column value (`NUMBER` in this case), and return the result subset with the smallest rank.